# Folder in /tmp won't delete despite the computer being restarted

Tags: files, permissions, sudo, tmp

There is a folder in `/tmp/` that won't delete despite my computer being restarted. I know it's not being recreated at restart since the last edited and added date is 23 November 2015. I do know which program it belongs to, but I have uninstalled every last part of it. `sudo rm -rf` and `sudo mv` gives me `operation not permitted`, as well as `directory not empty`. I have had this before but my solution was moving them to `/tmp/`. The permissions are `0755` and I am not allowed to change them, including in sudo.

It's also not a big deal if they are not deleted, since take up 0 K space, but I just thought it was weird.

Moving them to `/private/var/folders/f8/*/Cleanup At Startup` did not delete the files either.

Comment: Are they locked files? `/private/var` smells like OS X and el capitan adds System Integrity Protection (SIP) that could make for undeletable files. I think there's flags on `ls` to show these flags, but my Mac is at home.

Comment: @thrig, when I think about it they are very likely files protected by SIP, however I can't turn SIP off because my recovery partition is broken.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `# lsattr -d /tmp/FOLDER`. If flag `i` is set (inmutable), then disable if `#chattr -i /tmp/FOLDER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are files protected by SIP, which can be turned off by booting into the Recovery Partition and running `csrutil disable`.

Answer (score 0):

`lsof` will tell you what program has files open in that directory.  End the process and then `rm -rf` the directory.  If there aren't any open files in that directory then it's possible you have some filesystem corruption.  Since `/tmp` is probably part of your root filesystem you'll need to force `fsck` at the next reboot.  Use `sudo shutdown -rF now` to do that (the `-F` flag forces `fsck` on reboot).  After the `fsck` is done try `rm -rf`ing the files again.

Comment: Hm.. weird, `/tmp` isn't even mentioned in `lsof`.

Comment: I guess the bigger question is what is the problem with the directory staying there?  Does it just bug you or is it causing problems?